# Jrebel, Spring MVC and TIles. Can't get Jrebel to pick up changes to views.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tiles, jrebel

I'm trying to use Jrebel with IntelliJ 10. I'm working on Spring Roo generated project which uses tiles. There are multiple views.xml in my class path.

What I would like to know is if JRebel will pick up changes to views.xml. So far I can't seem to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just report it to JRebel forum - it will be registered as a feature request

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring roo generated project than it uses tiles 2.2.1 at least. in that case you dont need Jrebel to do it as Tiles can do it directly, just set the **useMutableTilesContainer** and **checkRefresh** properties to true on spring's TilesConfigurer bean

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
   id="tilesConfigurer" >
<property name="useMutableTilesContainer">true</property>
<property name="checkRefresh">true</property>
```

it's explained in detail here: http://lalyos.github.com/blog/2012/08/29/tiles-reload-definitions-in-springmvc/

Comment: You need to disclose when linking to your own blog.